# Problem with starting Vaadin Designer in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin-designer

Trying to start a Vaadin designer plugin in IntelliJ Idea (2021.3.3).

But when i trying to create new Vaadin 10+ design
via [image]

I'm getting a gray window "Please wait, loading view..."

In IDEA there is a WARN:

OS: MacOS Monterey 12.3

```
2022-04-13 14:32:14,146 [ 286697]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl - 'VaadinEditorLeftmostToolbar' toolbar by default uses any focused component to update its actions. Toolbar actions that need local UI context would be incorrectly disabled. Please call toolbar.setTargetComponent() explicitly. 
java.lang.Throwable: toolbar creation trace
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(ActionToolbarImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(ActionManagerImpl.java:420)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.CommonToolbarActionsProvider.getActionsToolbar(CommonToolbarActionsProvider.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.VaadinDesignWebEditor.createToolbarGroup(VaadinDesignWebEditor.java:707)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.VaadinDesignWebEditor.createToolbar(VaadinDesignWebEditor.java:661)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.VaadinDesignWebEditor.<init>(VaadinDesignWebEditor.java:229)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.flow.FlowEditorProvider.createAndConfigureEditor(FlowEditorProvider.java:127)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.flow.P3FileEditorProvider.createAndConfigureEditor(P3FileEditorProvider.java:94)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.AbstractDesignerEditorProvider.createEditor(AbstractDesignerEditorProvider.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4Edt(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1004)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl4$17(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:976)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.runBulkTabChange(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1793)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl4$18(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:975)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:972)
    at com.jetbrains.rdserver.fileEditors.BackendServerFileEditorManager.openFileImpl4(BackendServerFileEditorManager.kt:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl2$14(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:898)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:150)
....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While this is no solution (yet), the designer team seems to be aware of this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2435 and working on it. Have you tried with the latest (as of writing) version 4.6.17?

I presume it is one of the many programs having hiccups with the new macs.